# Change char struct field by pointer in c

Tags: c, embedded, iot, esp8266

I am pretty much desperate as I struggle with c pointers :-(.

I have a struct with char fields for storing configuration values in the flash memory of an ESP8266. This worked in the previous firmware version like a charm. However, I decided to go through a major SDK / firmware upgrade and build everything new. But As soon as I want to change the settings the system crashes. Here's my settings-struct and the associated functions

```
typedef struct{
    char device_id[11];
    char sta_ssid[32];
...
} SYSCFG;

void CFG_Save(SYSCFG *sysCfg);
void CFG_Load(SYSCFG *sysCfg);
void CFG_Init(SYSCFG *sysCfg);
```

The initialization of the settings is:

```
void CFG_Init(SYSCFG *sysCfg)
{
    memset(sysCfg, 0, sizeof(SYSCFG));
    uint8_t mac[6];
    char devId[11]; 
    esp_efuse_mac_get_default(mac);
    sprintf(devId, "ESP_%02X%02X%02X", mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
    strncpy((char *)sysCfg->device_id, (char *)&devId, 10);
    sysCfg->customConfig = 0;
    CFG_Save(sysCfg);
}
```

and that works as I see the debug output and no crash occurs. Also the Loading works, but as soon as I do the following, it crashes.

```
printf("saving key: %s, input: %s, size: %d\r\n", key, input, sizeof(config->sta_ssid) - 1);
strncpy(config->sta_ssid, input, sizeof(config->sta_ssid) - 1);
```

It does output the debug message, though:

```
saving key: ssid, input: Netgear, size: 31
```

I allocate memory in my main function:

```
SYSCFG *sysCfg;
sysCfg = malloc(sizeof(SYSCFG));
```

What am i doing wrong.

Comment: There's no need to write `(char *)&devId`. Just write `devId`.

Comment: You're right, that was because of countless tries, but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem As long as `strlen(input) < sizeof(config->sta_ssid)` there's shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you get the crash reason details?

Comment: Looks like the kind of thing that should be easy to work out using a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

- `sysCfg = malloc(sizeof(SYSCFG));` This is uninitialized memory.
- `sprintf(devId, "ESP_%02X%02X%02X"` This creates a string of 10 characters + null termination
- `strncpy((char *)sysCfg->device_id, (char *)&devId, 10);` This copies 10 characters and **no** null termination, because strncpy was never meant to be used for null-terminated strings to begin with. It's a dangerous function which should be avoided entirely.
- (Casting from `char*` to `char*` is senseless, but that's not the source of the bug.)

Solution: `strcpy(sysCfg->device_id, devId);`

For details check out [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Comment: He might have to check also, if malloc actually works (a heap is configured) and returned not NULL.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Same result.

Comment: @Peter Then fix this bug and move on to the next. You may have multiple bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes and think to narrow in on the problem. In my main file I have now:

```
SYSCFG sysCfg;
SYSCFG * const cfgPtr = &sysCfg;
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Custom Config: %d, Address: %p", sysCfg.customConfig, cfgPtr);
```

which gives me:

```
I (538) ota: Custom Config: 0, Address: 0x3ffea704
```

Then I call

```
openssl_server(cfgPtr, &ssids);


void openssl_server(SYSCFG *config, char (*ssids)[1024])
{
    sprintf("pointer address: %p\n", config);
    ...
```

and it crashes when it should print the pointer address.

```
Core  0 panic'ed (LoadStoreError). Exception was unhandled.
```

Something seems to be off in the passing of the address.